# Select of form can not change value by click on, when I use jquery on change

Tags: jquery

Select of form can not change right value by clicks, when I use jquery on change.
Although I tested (by alert), value on select option is correct.

But because it can not click, so it can not give correct value. Especially in the middle element

[See my select form which is not able to click correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmNZM.png)

Do you have any experience about select options in jquery which is wrong by this error?

This is code make this error:
If I give wrong value for "sample_id" variable, the select form will be normal
But select will error when this variable is correct.

```
 $("#sample").on("change", function(){
     var sample = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
```

...

```
    var sample_id = sample.split(" ")[sample.split(" ").length - 1]; //Error looks like from this line
    
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= count_sample; i++) {
        var data_i = data[i - 1];
        var id = data_i.id;
        
        if (id == sample_id) {
            var sample_order = i - 1;
            break;
        };
    };
    
    var datai = data[sample_order];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-` in `split`
Here is your solution https://codepen.io/babarkhan/pen/MWJMvey

Comment: It has the same error, when try to change " " to "-"

Comment: Check the codepen link and open the codepen console, then change the dropdown options, you will see the output. @cmdntd